# Intune - Entra joined devices showing as Registered

Tags: microsoft-intune

I have a total of 600 devices in my environment. These devices are joined to Intune through the Autopilot process. All devices show as Corporate-owned within Intune. However, about 15 devices show as Registered instead of Joined.

These devices are a mix of auto-deployed and user-deployed profiles. As far as I can see, all relevant configs and policies have applied so I'm unsure as to why they still show as Registered. Ideas on how this can be resolved?

Comment: What research have you done so far regarding this? Also, I believe this belongs over on our SysAdmin-focused sister site, ServerFault. I've voted to have it moved, but I recommend that you add more information, like logs and details and what you've researched and tried so far.

Comment: If you only have a 'registered' entry for those devices, check whether they were added with a personal Microsoft account or another local account? Or they may have failed to enroll in Intune for some reason. There is(was?) a known issue where autopilot can leave behind a duplicate 'Registered' entry for hybrid Joined devices: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/autopilot/known-issues#duplicate-device-objects-with-hybrid-azure-ad-deployments